# Вопросительный знак или двоеточие?

Tags: пунктуация

Оборот такого рода: "А если питомец, например, такой..." Далее следует фотография. По идее, конечно, вопросительный знак нужно было бы поставить после фотографии, а перед ней - двоеточие. Но после фотографии он уже не будет читаться.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как лучше всего оформить такое предложение?

Comment: А если Вы, dear 785, пахнете так... Далее следует флакон с сероводородом. Что "по идее" следует поставить перед флаконом, а что - после флакона?

Comment: Если это была шутка, то она Вам не удалась. Я бы советовала Вам извиниться перед пользователем.  
С надеждой на понимание,  
администратор

Comment: Это не шутка.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поскольку картинка всё-таки не текст, да и оторванный знак потеряется (особенно при большой картинке), думаю, можете смело ставить его после слова "такой".